# CASE WHERE change operator - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I was wondering if you could do a case statement in the `WHERE` clause which changes the operator.

What I am trying to do is filter out results based on a boolean value.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE 
      CASE @Status
          WHEN 1 THEN Name LIKE 'SOMETHING%'
          WHEN 2 THEN Name NOT LIKE 'SOMETHING%'
      END
```

I was wondering if this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CASE for WHERE field IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114815/using-case-for-where-field-in)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it without a `SWITCH` expression, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    (@Status = 1 AND Name LIKE 'SOMETHING%')
OR  (@Status = 2 AND Name NOT LIKE 'SOMETHING%')
```

Since `@Status` can be equal to only one thing at a time, only one component of the `OR` expression would determine the outcome of the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Amazing, so simple, why didnt i think of that!

Comment: Bit of logic, I previously used it many times but logic was pretty clear then.